# svg zoom out text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, svg

I used d3.js to make a svg-graph,It have zoom function,but It can`t zoom out text .I know chrome`s mimnum text-size is 12px. but  I need to zoom out my text in my graph, because of my text is in circle when I zoomed graph,circle change to small  but text doesn`t change.Is there any good way? [my excample](https://jsfiddle.net/58ggc7qk/)

Comment: *"I know chromes mimnum text-size is 12px"*. I beg your pardon?

Comment: Is’nt? I see others say..

Answer (score 0):

recently  css  `text-rendering:geometricPrecision` can deal this problem